# How can I get comments_fbid from Facebook's graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We use Facebook's comments plugin for users to post comment on our pages. I wanted to fetch the Facebook comments using Facebook's graph API. The API call is pretty straightforward :

Example : GET /v2.6/<**comments_fbid**>/comments

This works from the [Facebook graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

However, I am getting this **comments_fbid** using this URL :

https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=[my-site-url]&format=json

Sample response:

```
[
   {
    url: "<my-url>",
    normalized_url: "<my-url>",
    share_count: 33412170,
    like_count: 28816093,
    comment_count: 8485499,
    total_count: 70713762,
    click_count: 0,
    comments_fbid: "10150187081535131",
    commentsbox_count: 5197
   }
]
```

This is an undocumented (and possibly deprecated?) API. How can I get the **comments_fbid** from the call to the graph API? Am I missing something here?

This is the same id on the hyperlink for the moderation tool on the page if you're signed in :

//developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/url/<**comments_fbid**>/pending/descending/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to test without your actual site URL, but I think you want something like this:

`GET /v2.6/?id=http://www.Facebook.com&fields=og_object`

Documentation is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/url/

Comment: I did try that but the id you get from this call : ?id=http://www.Facebook.com&fields=og_object is different from the comments_fbid you get from https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.facebook.com&format=json. I can only get results for comments_fbid/comments and not for og_object_id/comments